# fetch descending order but display as ascending in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch last records but display as ascending order not descending order.

```
 SELECT R.cr_id, 
        R.time, 
        R.reply, 
        U.id, 
        U.username,
        U.firstname, 
        U.lastname, 
        U.email, 
        U.image 
     FROM (HM_customers U, HM_conversation_reply R) 
     WHERE R.user_id_fk = U.id AND R.c_id_fk = '1' 
     ORDER BY R.cr_id DESC LIMIT 20
```

Edit...

I am using two tables.

Comment: SELECT * FROM (...)x ORDER BY ...

Comment: I am using two tables in same query...

Comment: I think you'd have to do something like putting the results into an array and then reverse it

Comment: @Strawberry, can you explain this How I can do this with two tables. I have given my sql query in my question.

Comment: @Darren Sweeney, I have done this same using php but I want to learn this in mysql.

Comment: Just put everything you already wrote inside the parentheses !?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below code working for me.

```
   SELECT t.cr_id, 
    t.time, 
    t.reply, 
    t.id, 
    t.username,
    t.firstname, 
    t.lastname, 
    t.email, 
    t.image 
 FROM (
 SELECT R.cr_id, 
    R.time, 
    R.reply, 
    U.id, 
    U.username,
    U.firstname, 
    U.lastname, 
    U.email, 
    U.image 
 FROM (HM_customers U, HM_conversation_reply R) 
 WHERE R.user_id_fk = U.id AND R.c_id_fk = '1' 
 ORDER BY R.cr_id DESC
 limit 20
 ) t
 ORDER BY t.cr_id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT R.cr_id,  
    R.time,  
    R.reply,  
    U.id,  
    U.username, 
    U.firstname,  
    U.lastname,  
    U.email,  
    U.image  
 FROM HM_customers U, HM_conversation_reply R  
 ON R.user_id_fk = U.id   
 WHERE R.c_id_fk = '1'  
 GROUP BY R.cr_id
 ORDER BY R.cr_id DESC LIMIT 20
```

Comment: this is same thing... like my query

Comment: I added a GROUP BY R.cr_id  so it will group by that and show in desending order

Comment: not fulfill my requirements... I am getting same result.

Comment: This is terrible. :-(

Answer (score -1):

```
 SELECT R.cr_id, 
        R.time, 
        R.reply, 
        U.id, 
        U.username,
        U.firstname, 
        U.lastname, 
        U.email, 
        U.image 
     FROM HM_customers U join HM_conversation_reply R
     WHERE R.user_id_fk = U.id AND R.c_id_fk = '1' 
     ORDER BY R.cr_id DESC LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score -4):

Change

```
ORDER BY R.cr_id DESC LIMIT 20
```

to

```
ORDER BY R.cr_id ASC LIMIT 20
```